# Depth of conditional nesting rules in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin, codenarc

I am doing some Static Code Analysis (SCA) on my Grails application.

I have to check 'Depth of conditional nesting', but I am not able to find any Grails plugins do that.

In CheckStyle (for Java projects (code)) there is NestedForDepth, NestedIfDepth and NestedTryDepth. But I am not able to found these in any of Grails SCA plugins.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [GMetrics](http://www.grails.org/plugin/gmetrics) plugin can help you. It is based on the [GMetrics](http://gmetrics.sourceforge.net/) groovy library.

I think you can't measure 'Depth of conditional nesting' directly with GMetrics. However, you can measure the cyclomatic complexity of methods (which somehow correlates with the 'Depth of conditional nesting').

Comment: sorry, not available in GMetrics